# Android: Trying to launch the music player from my app with an input playlist

Tags: android, android-intent, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm trying to start the stock music player from my app. I did see a few stackoverflow questions like this one - [Intent to open android playlist activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788156/intent-to-open-android-playlist-activity) - but that didn't get me anywhere. This is the code I am trying to use right now -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName
        ("com.android.music","PlaylistBrowserActivity"));
intent.setType(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.CONTENT_TYPE);
intent.setFlags(0x10000000);
intent.putExtra("oneshot", false);
intent.putExtra("playlist", playlistid);
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

I hit this exception -

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.playlistsonthego/com.example.playlistsonthego.HomeSceen}:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.android.music/PlaylistBrowserActivity}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: You should really not hardcode the package of your component...

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
 intent.setType(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.CONTENT_TYPE);     
 intent.putExtra("playlist", playlistid);
 intent.putExtra("oneshot", false); 
 startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

what I have changed is from ACTION_VIEW to ACTION_PICK.

Comment: Thanks Prashant! I hit the same exception with ACTION_PICK too, though. And if I remove the setComponent, I get a No Activity found to handle intent exception.