# Titanium how to open playlist android

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

Does anyone know how to open the **playlist** in android..It is working on **IOS**..But Android is there anyway we can implement this?.

On **IOS** you can use `Ti.Media.openMusicLibrary()`..

Any help?

Comment: you can try to open playlist activity using intents, [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788156/intent-to-open-android-playlist-activity) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found on gitTio:

http://gitt.io/component/com.alcoapps.androidplaylists